# How to use Mobirise Icons in html

Tags: html, icons, mobirise

i want to use Mobirise Icons Cheatsheet but it give me this error in the console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAbXC.png)
I download it and link it like this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobiriseicons/mobiriseicons/16 px/mobirise/style.css">
```

I tried to add font folder in the same directory but it didn't work for me
NOTE: i download it from thhis website (https://mobiriseicons.com/cheatsheet.html)
any suggestion